# How to display multiple labels when polygons overlap in Carto?

Tags: carto

I have a polygon layer in Carto where polygons overlap.  I need to display both sets of attributes for overlapping polygons when a user clicks on them.  Is this possible?

For example if PolygonA has attribute NAME=A and PolygonB is NAME=B and the two overlap, and I click on the area where they overlap, I want to see an info window, or multiple windows, that show both A and B.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with default BUILDER interactivity behavior. You need to do a custom application and use the SQL API to interrogate the layer by the position to get all the features that intersect it.

Comment: Your solution is a bit over my head so trying to simplify scope.  What if i just want to have the overlapping area labelled with both values without the user clicking on the overlap?  It seems I can display the polygon to indicate there is an overlap with the composite operation options, but I can't see a similar kind of display trick for the labels.  Any suggestions for that?

Comment: nothing aside of allowing overlapping labels, sorry